# How to load Node and Paragraphs using target_revision_id?

Tags: paragraphs

In Drupal 8, How to load Node and Paragraphs using `target_revision_id`?

For node I used `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nodeId);` . I tried this for revision id: `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadRevision($vid);`

Answer (score 1):

The second line probably should be:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph')->loadRevision($target_revision_id)
```

It is recommended, though, to load the referenced entities through the field:

The first paragraph:

```
$paragraph = $node->{$field_name}->entity;
```

The second paragraph:

```
$paragraph = $node->{$field_name}->get(1)->entity;
```

All paragraphs:

```
$paragraphs = $node->{$field_name}->referencedEntities();
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Let me check this.